# How to populate listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm trying to populate list box with list of files. The structure for these files is as follows:

```
-abc (main folder)
   -xyz (sub folder)
      -123 (sub folder within xyz)
      -6678 (subfolder within xyz)
      -qwerty.csv (subfile within xyz)
      -vbnm.csv (subfile within xyz).
```

I want a way to display only qwerty and vbnm in the listbox. Please note that the path is set through app.config file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you have mistaken the purpose of this site. We're here to help you with problems or specific questions, not write the code for you. Please take a moment to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Here's to point you in the right direction: [**`Directory.GetFiles()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How to ask a question: [Ask]; How SO works: the [Tour].  Visit both soon.